# Change color based on distance from object

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, three.js, glsl

I have two objects: let's call them object1 and object2. I can move object2 around, and I want to change the color of object2 based on its distance from object1. How can I do this in GLSL? I'm very new to this, but I think I'm supposed to pass a matrix from the vertex shader to a fragment shader, though I'm not sure which one.

Answer (score 0):

Distance between 2 objects cannot be calculated in Vertex shaders, at least in OpenGL ES this is not possible.

Vertex shader, as the name implies, has access to only the data relevant to that p[articular vertex.

So, the right solution for your problem would be to feed the Object2 with the color through uniform variables. Color will be calculated based on the distance between the objects and just the color alone can be fed into OpgnGL.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. In which file would I feed object2 to? I thought we control colors in the fragment shader file. Currently I have a vertex shader file for object1, a vertex shader file for object2, a fragment shader file for object1, and a fragment shader file for object2.

Answer (score 0):

The way you could imagine doing this in the vertex or fragment shader would be to send the position of object 1 (or its model matrix) when you draw object 2, and vice-versa. You can then have something like (note this is not gl-es syntax, I've never used it)

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_position;

layout (location = 0) out float out_distance;

uniform mat4 u_model;
uniform mat4 u_otherObjectModel;
uniform mat4 u_view;
uniform mat4 u_proj;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_proj * u_view * u_model * vec4(in_position, 1.0);
    vec3 p0 = vec3(u_model * vec4(in_position, 1.0));

    // Here I consider the model is centered on zero
    vec3 p1 = vec3(u_otherObjectModel * vec4(0, 0, 0, 1));
    out_dist = length(p0 - p1);
}
```

There are two main drawbacks for this method (one implying the other)

- You compute the distance for each vertex of the current object, and do this for both objects which might not be super efficient
- Since you compute the distance between each vertex of one object, and the center of the other, the objects will not have a unique color.

What I would do, as pointed out by codetiger, is not computing the distance on the GPU, but do it on the CPU (in one of your game logic files) and then send the computed distance using uniform variable. It will be ways more efficient, simpler to use and you will have only one color per vertex.